# How to update Unity3D from 4.3.4 to 4.5.1 properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, version, project

I downloaded 4.5.1 and opened my project in it. The problem is that somethings become different. For example, the angular damping value of my object was 0.05 in 4.3.4 but now it is 0.5 and it ruins the whole project. But I want to use 4.5.1. Is there any way to move the project properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a backup of the project you won't be able to revert to the previous version without making the project from scratch.

Now assuming that you do have a version in 4.3.4; just make sure that it is saved and then you can open a scene from the project using the new version of Unity3D.

I just updated my own project to 4.5.1 and all stayed the same.

Comment: thanks. I have a backup. I think in 4.5.1 physics2d works differently and weird. applied forces show different results etc.